# Add template page from plugin - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add page template from my plugin. So when user go to add new page, in "Template" drop-down menu should appear my template page from plugin. So user will be able to choose my template from plugin for new page.

Template file should be located in my plugin directory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this well written article on the subject.  It's not a plugin in itself, but rather shows you how to write exactly what you are looking to do inside your own plugin:

http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/